# Why is the length of this expression 11?

Tags: r

```
x <- c(10.4, 5.6, 3.1, 6.4, 21.7)
y <- c(x, 0, x)
v <- 2*x + y + 1
```

> generates a new vector v of length 11 constructed by adding together, element by element, 2*x repeated 2.2 times, y repeated just once, and 1 repeated 11 times.

[Page 7: CRAN's Intro to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf)

Please explain how the length is 11?

Comment: What is x and what is y? Could you please add all necessary details to the question without sending us to an external link? The linked doc is 100 pages long!

Comment: Bhaskar, you're missing the two assignments that occur earlier in that PDF: `x <- c(10.4, 5.6, 3.1, 6.4, 21.7)` and `y <- c(x, 0, x)`.

Comment: The reason it's length 11 is because `y` is length 11 (length of `x`, then length 1, then length of `x` again, so 5+1+5=11), and `x` is "recycled" sufficient times to extend that far out.

Answer (score 4):

The text above that section in the book says:

> Vectors occurring in the same expression need not all be of the same
>   length. If they are not, the value of the expression is a vector with
>   the same length as the longest vector which occurs in the expression.

In other words, the longest vector in the expression here is `y`, which has length 11. The resulting vector therefore has length 11.

```r
x <- c(10.4, 5.6, 3.1, 6.4, 21.7)
y <- c(x, 0, x)
length(x)
#> [1] 5
length(y)
#> [1] 11
```

It goes on to say that:

> Shorter vectors in the expression are recycled as often as need be
>   (perhaps fractionally) until they match the length of the longest
>   vector.

What this means is that in order to add the two vectors, you need to first make them the same length. The way this is done is that you *recycle* the vectors until they are the same length. This is to say that in this situation `2 * x + y` is equivalent to `2 * (c(x, x, x[1])) + y`. You repeat the shorter vector until you can't fit a full one in, and then include elements to make up the difference. `c(x, x, x[1])` has length 11, which is the same as the length of `y`.

Comment: Great answer, Calum You, much better than my terse comment.

Comment: Thanks CalumYou, 2.2 times is what made it confusing.